# Personalising Gmail canned responses

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

There is a great tool called 'canned response' at Gmail but how can I make it produce responses that are customised?

Sample template I want to create:

> Dear %FIRSTNAME%,
>
> Thank you blah-blah-blah...
>
> (<-put cursor here)
>
> Please find this attached.

Does Gmail have macro definitions and do the canned responses allow for attachments?

Comment: It's not really that sophisticated.

Comment: It is still a Labs feature, though, so I'd suggest sending feedback to get that sort of functionality added. http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=labs&selected=canned

Answer (score 1):

This feature isn't available in the canned responses lab.